# plotly.graph_objs.Line deprecated

Tags: python, plotly, data-analysis

I'm getting this message:

plotly.graph_objs.Line is deprecated.
Please replace it with one of the following more specific types

- plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line
- plotly.graph_objs.layout.shape.Line

Any suggestion on how could I fix it?
Code:

```
mortalidade_covid = round((covid_mortes/covid_casos)*100,2)

datas = mortalidade_covid.index

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Line(name='Mortalidade em %', x=datas, y=mortalidade_covid, mode="lines+markers")    
])

fig['layout'].update(title="Taxa de Mortalidade", title_x=0.5, xaxis_title='Meses', yaxis_title='Taxa de Mortalidade')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `go.Line` with `go.Scatter`.